# Moving application in background on back button event

Tags: android

Is it possible to move the app in background when we click on device back button in android?

background means application moves to screen(application) from where it launches ?

Comment: it is possible like some download manager run in background while click back button....!

Comment: Please allow the BACK button to behave normally.

Comment: @commonsWare - I know BACK button should behave normally, but this is one of feature in my current application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will prefer to use below code to move application in background

```
       @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        switch(keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
              if(isTaskRoot()) {
               Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
               homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
               homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               startActivity(homeIntent);
               return true;
                }
            else {
             super.keyDown(keyCode,event);
             return false;      
        }

    default: 
    super.keyDown(keyCode,event);
           return false;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 39):

Try Using

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

            moveTaskToBack(true);

            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `moveTaskToBack(true)` does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Kotlin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) { moveTaskToBack(true) }
}
```

Comment: I had to write:

`onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                moveTaskToBack(true)
            }
        })`