# How to minimise/hide app programmatically?

Tags: android

I have an activity which is purely transparent (user can't see when it gets open).I open this activity from background service whenever I want to open it. After doing some work, I need to close that activity (not `finish()`).I want to `hide` or `minimize` app. Actually, my app opens up for a second and do `someWork` after doing `someWork`, it continues to do remaining work (some uploading process) in background i.e. in `onPause`.I don't want user to know that something opens & closed immediately.

Currently, I am using below code-

```
public void minimizeApp() {
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Now, Problem is that If user is using some other app eg, playing game or using Whatsapp, When my app get opens over previous app(Game or Whatsapp) and `minimizeApp()` is called then it minimises my app along with other app opened in background.
I want to minimize **only** my app.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need an activity to do some work? Is `Service` not good enough?

Comment: @Sangharsh, services sometimes can't do all the works we need.Some tasks can be done only from `activity` class. And in my case, i did every task silently in transparent activity, so that user can't see what's happening.It's kind of spy app.

Comment: can you try solution provided in this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461095/moving-application-in-background-on-back-button-event

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try the following from the activity/context from where you want to minimise the app:

```
YourActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
```