# Translucent android activity opens but leaves colored background until pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, translucency

I'm creating a main activity for my application that has no GUI so I've added

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

to my application tag in my manifest and in my main activity onCreate method I've added

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
);
```

When I run the application from my IDE it works great. When I install the APK and run the application directly from the device, the app opens just fine, but it leaves whatever the "cold start" splash screen is covering the entire device. As soon as it's pressed it disappears but in addition the press still registers to what was underneath because of my no touch flags maybe? The color of the background that is left up changes depending where the app is launched form, if launched from the app drawer, it's white because that's the background android uses when launching it, but if i create a shortcut on my phone desktop and launch from there it uses a blue backgroudn because that's the icon background color of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Finding this article helped me with a solution. I don't know if it's the right solution, but it worked, and this app is just for me anyway. I just sent my activity to the back.

[How to minimise/hide app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068501/how-to-minimise-hide-app-programmatically)